# Resizing a UIView to make it scrollable in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I added a UIScrollView in my appDelegate, and then did

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(720, 480);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Where view Controller loads up a UIView.  In IB, I set the size of the UIView to be 720x480, but it's not showing up any larger when I run.   I can scroll around my UIView to blank white space that is 720x480, but I want my UIView to be resized to this size too.  I checked the arguments in the initial drawRect rect, and they are still only 320x480, so it seems that I have to do something else to set the size of my UIView, other than resize it in IB?

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by changing the frame size of the view from the viewControllers ViewDidLoad method.   Apparently the controller was constraining the UIView size, even though I set it as larger in IB.